Pointer event clientX is wrong within Android Webviews?
I have some touch event handlers, e.g.:
window.addEventListener('pointermove', e => console.log(e.touches[0].clientX));

If I slide in my finger from the left edge of the screen, on Android Chrome, I can get clientX to be pretty close to 0px. Within an Android Webview, I can't go lower than 10px. This seems like a bug where Android adds some offset to clientX.
safe-area-inset-left is 0. I can repro on a Pixel 8 and a Pixel 5, so it's not an issue with my device.
Is this a known bug or is there something I'm doing wrong? E.g. am I supposed to subtract something from clientX to get the true number of pixels from the left edge of the screen?
